# make Gtk window transparent using css

Tags: python, gtk3

i m using python.
How to make Gtk window tranparent using css?
for instance

```
*{ 
    background-color:transparent; 
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

this makes all the labels in the window tranparent but window itself is not tranparent.
how do i achive this ?

Comment: Not to sure, about Python and GTK windows but `*` in typical web-CSS selects all the elements and applies the style properties. Might have to target the specific element with a specific identifier.

Comment: I think cairo does that better for you,